# Efficient and Fast merger for multiple .CSV files

Tags: python, pandas

I have more than 15M tweets and I need to merger the ID and Text after dropping duplicates. I need most efficient way to do this as it is taking very long to complete?

```
   frames = []
   missed = 0
   for q in query_list:
       hashtag = q + '.csv'
       try:
            file_data = pd.read_csv(path + hashtag ,encoding='utf-8')
            frames.append(file_data)
       except:
            missed+= 1
            continue

   df = pd.concat(frames)
   df = df[['id','text']]
   df = df.drop_duplicates()
   df.to_csv('row_tweets.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: as you seem to use only 2 columns you may speed up things a bit by just reading these 2 columns by specifying `usecols = ['id','text']` in `read_csv`

Comment: I add this however, it is the duplicate removal which is taking very long time to complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you want unique pairs of `(id, text)`, I'd just do it in pure python using `set` for easy de-duplication, and csv readers/writers:

```
import csv
id_text_pairs = set()  # set of (id, text) pairs
missed = 0
for q in query_list:
    hashtag = q + '.csv'
    try:
        with open(path + hashtag, 'r') as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            for row in reader:
                id_text_pairs.add( (row['id'], row['text']) ) # this won't add duplicates
    except:
        missed += 1
        continue

with open('row_tweets.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    col_names = ['id', 'text']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=col_names)
    writer.writeheader() # First line is the 'id,text' header
    for id, text in id_text_pairs:
        writer.writerow({'id': id, 'text': text})  # write each id,text pair
```

That should do it, and I believe will be more efficient in de-duping than a huge dataframe call at the end. Note that if your `text`'s contain commas, you might want to output in tab-delimited format using the DictWriter argument `delimiter='\t'`, or the `quotechar` and `quoting` arguments, check out the csv documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).